# implement code for all elements except the first element

Tags: jquery

i have this code:-

```
    $('.details-comment-bg').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+580) {
            $(this).addClass("slideUp");
        }
    });
```

I want to do to implement this code for all elements except the first element.

how can i do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.details-comment-bg:not(:eq(0))').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+580) {
            $(this).addClass("slideUp");
        }
    });
```

can also use

```
 $('.details-comment-bg:not(:first)').each(function(){...
```

reference [eq-selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) and  [not-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [first-selector](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

```
$('.details-comment-bg:not(:first)').each(function(){
        //Your code
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$('.details-comment-bg:not(:first-child)').each(function(){
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;

        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow+580) {
            $(this).addClass("slideUp");
        }
    });
```